# Output the LIB file in a different place than the DLL with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, directory

When I build my **DLL** with *Microsoft Visual Studio (2012)*, apart from the **.dll** file I also get the **.lib** file along with an **.exp** file. They are created in the same directory as the **.dll** but I want the **.lib** to go to another directory.
Can I change it from the project's properties or must be some command in the post-build event section? In that case, what would it be?

Comment: Just change the Linker + Advanced + Import Library setting.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you and how did you manage to know all this ? did you digg visual studio settings and vcxproj? or just searched for output parameters? :)

Comment: I don't remember, it's been too long ago.  I always dig, but it could have been as simple as pressing F1 at the property page.